# Why doesn’t this code compile? Reassignment of specific type of struct inside lambda causes error C2512: no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I have a struct with 2 members, it relies on the first member to calculate the value of the second.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
   int memberA = 0;
   int memberB = memberA + 5;
};

int main()
{
   auto SomeLambda = []()
   {
      SomeStruct x;
      x = SomeStruct{};
   };

   SomeStruct x;
   x = SomeStruct{};
   return 0;
}
```

I want to reassign that struct to reinitialise it and reuse the variable name. I can do this in a regular function, HOWEVER if I do it inside a lambda I get the following compilation error.

```
main.cpp(12): error C2512: 'SomeStruct': no appropriate default constructor available
main.cpp(12): note: Invalid aggregate initialization
```

If I remove the inter dependency between members the code compiles fine.

```
struct SomeStruct
{
   int memberA = 0;
   int memberB = 5;
};
```

If I change the assignment inside the lambda to use parenthesis instead of braces that also allows the code to compile.

```
SomeStruct x;
x = SomeStruct();
```

However the assignment outside the lambda is still using braces.

Can anyone tell me why this assignment of a specific type of struct inside a lambda fails to compile on MSVC?

Comment: FWIW, your example compiles with gcc

Comment: This is a knowledge seeking question, I'm just wondering why it doesn't compile specifically when its inside a lambda.

Comment: Your lambda is never invoked, so it's elided by the compiler.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug

Comment: For me code looks fine, I think issue is with compiler. Please check how to select compiler version in MSVC and choose c++17 or else your compiler needs update. 

In g++ compiler, the command to choose compiler version is 
`g++ --std=c++17 main.cpp`

Comment: @BhavithC, I can reproduce it with latest VS2019. Looks like a quite persistent bug.

Comment: As a side-note, quite interesting, what might be the origin of the bug, see: https://cppinsights.io/s/a79aba93 . Might be the explicit scoped this-reference, maybe internal interference with the compiler's handling of the lambda's this, since the version with an in-struct initialization with a constexpr global works. Only speculation.

Comment: I suggest you go to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=62&entry=problem) to report this problem.